# Matlab -implementing hough line

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I have been writing my own code that implements the hough line and shows the first best line - my code works in degrees in intervals of 10 degrees - i have an array which is the size of the Diagonal of the photo *36 (Diagonal*36) basicly for each pixel it calcultes the rho (Radius can be seen in the code ) Rounds it  and puts it in the array of frequencies Later we switch from polar to a represntation of line  like y=ax+b a= shipu b =][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL105.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL105.png)hofshi rho =kav angel =zavit the results are not accurate heres the code

```
  function [ shipu,hofshi ] = newHoughLine( img )
[rows,cols] = size(img);
diagonal = round(sqrt((rows^2)+(cols^2)));
steta = zeros(diagonal,36);
for i =1:rows
   for j=1:cols
       for k=1:35
           if(img(i,j)==0)
             s=round((i*cosd(k*10))+(j*sind(k*10)));
             if(s~=0 & k~=18)
             steta(abs(s),k)= steta(abs(s),k)+1;
           end
       end        
   end
   end
 end

m=max(max((steta)))
[kav,zavit]=find(steta==m)
shipu= -(cosd(zavit(1)*10)/sind(zavit(1)*10))
hofshi = kav(1)*sind(zavit(1)*10)-(shipu*kav(1)*cosd(zavit(1)*10));
figure
imshow(img)
x0 = 1;
xend = size(img,2); %// Get the width of the image

    %// Compute starting y coordinate
    y0 = shipu*x0 + hofshi; %// Note theta in degrees to respect your convention

    %// Compute ending y coordinate
    yend = shipu*xend + hofshi;

    %// Draw the line
    line([x0 xend], [y0 yend], 'Color', 'red');
end
```

also the code takes a lot of time since matlab works as an interpeter I would like to improve it but the first priority is making it work better even approx
To make myself clear i would like to make sure it works better than now and find the lines

[image]

this is an example of my code running

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to make it work better to find lines

Comment: Does the posted code work? Better runtime-wise?

Comment: the code works and print the result above

Comment: Quoting from the question - "I would like to improve it **but the first priority is making it work ...** You might define `works` and `better` for us again?

Comment: That didn't really help. It's still a grammatical nightmare up there which is unclear in what you want. A) Does the code work? if no, what's the problem? If yes -> B) how slow is it now and why is that too slow?

Comment: To make things clear - A.the code works. B it is slow but this is not the main problem takes about a half minute this happens because of the 3 loops C . as you can see in the photo the line is not close enough to the one we want to find therfore  i want to fix it